# Stimulus JS Duplicating Elements and Disconnecting/ReConnecting

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

I am seeing odd behavior in stimulusJS, just going over the tutorial here:
https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/handbook/working-with-external-resources

I started tinkering with it toward the end I made some changes because it seemed like there were inconsistencies in the guide.

It is now connecting and disconnection, it `console.log`s repeatedly as I had one of those in the `connect` method.
It is also appending the entire DOM elements repeatedly.

there are no loops over elements. I stopped the server and started it, not sure what else could be causing it. There are no errors.

[image]

Source on Github: https://github.com/dmc2015/stimulus-starter

I was considering using it on a couple of projects instead of react/vue but if it's not reliable and doesn't communicate errors I'll pass.

one of the controllers:

```
// src/controllers/content_loader_controller.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static values = { url: String, refreshInterval: Number}

  connect() {
    this.load()
    // this.load_params()
    // if (this.hasRefreshIntervalValue) {
    //   this.startRefreshing()
    // }
  }

  disconnect() {
    this.stopRefreshing()
  }

  startRefreshing() {
    this.refreshTimer = setInterval(() => {
      this.load()
    }, this.refreshIntervalValue)
  }

  stopRefreshing() {
    if (this.refreshTimer) {
      clearInterval(this.refreshTimer)
    }
  }

  // load({ params }) {
  //   fetch(params.url)
  //     .then(response => response.text())
  //     .then(html => this.element.innerHTML = html)
  // }

  // loadTemplate( { params } ) {
  //   fetch(params.url)
  //     .then(response => response.text())
  //     .then(html => this.element.innerHTML = html)
  // }

  load() {
    fetch(this.urlValue)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(html => this.element.innerHTML = html)
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="bundle.js" async></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- <div data-controller="content-loader"
      data-content-loader-url-value="/messages.html"
      data-content-loader-refresh-interval-value="5000">
      <a href="#" data-content-loader-url-param="/messages.html" data-action="content-loader#load_params">Messages</a>
      <a href="#" data-content-loader-url-param="/comments.html" data-action="content-loader#load_params">Comments</a>
    </div> -->
    <div data-controller="content-loader">
      <a href="#" data-content-loader-url-param="/messages.html" data-action="content-loader#loadTemplate">Messages</a>
      <a href="#" data-content-loader-url-param="/comments.html" data-action="content-loader#loadTemplate">Comments</a>
    </div>

    <h1 data-controller="example"></h1>

    <div data-controller="hello">
      <input data-hello-target="name" type="text">
      <button data-action="click->hello#greet">Greet</button>
    </div>

    <!-- <div data-controller="clipboard">
      PIN: <input data-clipboard-target="source" type="text" value="">
      <button data-action="click->clipboard#copy">Copy to Clipboard</button>
    </div> -->

    <div data-controller="clipboard"  data-clipboard-supported-class="clipboard--supported">
      PIN: <textarea data-clipboard-target="source" type="text" value="234"></textarea>
      <button data-action="clipboard#copy" data-clipboard--supported-class="clipboard--supported" class="clipboard-button">Copy to Clipboard</button>
    </div>

    <div data-controller="slideshow" data-slideshow-index-value="0">
      <button data-action="slideshow#previous"> ← </button>
      <button data-action="slideshow#next"> → </button>
    
      <div data-slideshow-target="slide"></div>
      <div data-slideshow-target="slide"></div>
      <div data-slideshow-target="slide"></div>
      <div data-slideshow-target="slide"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the looks of your code changes, it appears you are loading the current page into the element every zero seconds. The urlValue will be empty as you are not setting this value anywhere in your html, the refresh interval is also empty, meaning zero. Did it work when you had the commented out html only?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the smallest possible code to reproduce your scenario (below), the Stimulus controller is working as documented but probably not as you expect.

#### Code

This should be the code that is producing your output as above.

```js
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

export default class extends Controller {
  static values = { url: String, refreshInterval: Number };

  connect() {
    this.load();
  }

  load() {
    fetch(this.urlValue)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((html) => (this.element.innerHTML = html));
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title"Content loader</h1>
      <div data-controller="content-loader">
        <strong>Content</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

### Explanation

#### 1. Default values from `getters`

In the [documentation on `this.[some]value` getters](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/values#getters), when you do not declare a value you will get the default value. The default for a string is just an empty string.

This means that your HTML, `<div data-controller="content-loader">`, which has no `data-content-loader-url-value` set will default to `''` (empty string).

#### 2. `connect` callback

One your controller connects, the [`connect`](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/lifecycle-callbacks#connection) callback will run, which in turn is calling your `this.load` method.

The `load` method will make a fetch request for the `urlValue`, which will be an empty string, which defaults to the current URL when using fetch.

#### 3. `innerHTML` update

Once the fetch resolves, it will pull in the full HTML of the current page, including another copy of the `<div data-controller="content-loader">` HTML. This creates another dynamically loaded controlled element inside 'content-loader'.

This will call that instance's connect/load methods and then the cycle repeats.

### Solution

To solve for this, remember to think about your controller's values and what their default will be if not provided.

You can even be intentional here by setting a default value that you want to use if none is provided. See https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/values#default-values

```js
export default class extends Controller {
  static values = {
    url: { default: '/path/to/content', type: String },
    refreshInterval: Number,
  };
// ...
```

As for your question about the docs:

> ... because it seemed like there were inconsistencies in the guide.

It would be great to get an understanding of the specific problem here, there is some confusing wording in the docs about using values that should be [fixed in a future release](https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus/pull/705) but maybe more work is needed.

As for the error handling;

> but if it's not reliable and doesn't communicate errors I'll pass.

I think it's good to understand how Stimulus works for errors before jumping to conclusions. In this scenario, there were no errors, but it's good to know that Stimulus will run all methods inside a try/catch and is actually quite good at logging errors when they exist. It's similar to a React boundary on each Controller's instance, but included by default.

However, when working with Promise, the same consideration as React/Vue will need to be applied. You will need to use `catch` or async/try/catch to catch errors that can happen async.

You can read more about [Stimulus error handling](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/handbook/installing#error-handling) on the documentation.